# Factory, dependency injection, or something else

Tags: design-patterns, language-agnostic, factory-pattern

What to do in situation of complex object creation like following:

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B(a);
C c = new C(b);
```

Should I try to create some kind of factory in this case, or to use dependency injection container, or perhaps some kind of builder?

To be concrete, I would like to achieve something like:

```
C c = factory.createC();
```

Comment: See if inheritance can be applied, if not dependency injection is the way to go.

Comment: You have chosen no language tag. Is it intentional? Or did you mean one (my guess would be Java)? Whatever the answer, could you please edit your question to add either the tag "language-agnostic" or the appropriate one?

Answer (score 2):

This will depend on a number of factors, including:

- The kind of interdependency between A, B and C (e.g. is it functional/method dependency, data dependency, or a mixture?)
- The lifecycle of each of A, B and C - singletons, per request (if it's in the context of something like a web API), per resolution, or something else
- Whether you can resolve the dependency graph at application startup (e.g. completely statically, or based on startup config) or whether resolution is dependent on data inputs that are only available during execution (e.g. request data for a web API)

Generally, for dependencies that can be resolved at application startup, dependency injection via IoC container is the way to go.

If you need data inputs during execution, then generally factories are the right approach, where you can provide the data inputs in the parameters to the factory methods, and the factory can return a correctly resolved instance for that set of inputs. Note that the factories themselves should still ideally be plugged into an IoC container.

For primarily data dependencies, you may want to consider builders.

For other scenarios like custom lifecycle, mixed functional + data dependencies, etc, you may need to use more customised approaches. Although if anything, the customisations would probably tend more towards factories or builders, but perhaps with the factories/builders themselves still using dependency injection and resolution via an IoC container.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Well, these are sort of wrappers for real data that are used for serialization in Hadoop framework. The idea is that when you want to serialize some object you create this sort of wrapper, so the client can serialize data by calling serialize methods of this wrappers. For example, you want to serialize a car, so the car will call serialize method of its wheels, wheel will call serialize of tires, etc. So I guess it's a mixture? What to do in that case?